# Redirect non-www to www for Mobile Browser

Tags: .htaccess

I have .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That is working perfect in desktop versions, but when I try on **mobile browser**, the redirection doesn't work.

Please help me what should I do

Answer (score 0):

Your mobile subdomain might be different. Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```